# Set focus to field using SSJS in Xpages?

Tags: xpages

I am validating my form using SSJS from a submit button.   To display the error to the user I am using the extension library dialog box.

How can I set the focus to the field failing validation, using SSJS?

One thing I might be able to do is use CSJS in the OK button of the dialog box.   I close it with the OK button as follows:

```
var errorField = '#{javascript:viewScope.get("errorField")}';
```

I tried the following but it does not seem to work.

```
if (errorField != null &&  errorField != "")
{   
var ef = document.getElementsByName("#{id:" + errorField + "}");
ef.focus();

}
```

I am setting the scope variable errorField when I  do the actual validation.

Comment: Just as an update.  I added an alert inside the if block above that displays the value of the scope variable and it does display the proper value.  So it is just the focus that is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes my bad on the missing colon. Ok tried it out and it doesn't seem to be working for me either when I break up the id expression.

you have a viewScope set to the id of the error field, is it possible for you to set that to :

```
getComponent('...').getClientId();
```

if you could do that the you would be able to run:

```
var errorField = '#{javascript:viewScope.get("errorField")}';

var ef = dojo.byId(errorField);
ef.focus();
```

that works fine for me.

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me.  Did you really mean getComponent('...').getClientId(); ?  getComponent has no such method.  So I tried getClientId('Field1');  and I did this when I set the viewScope in my SSJS.  What am I missing?

Comment: Only saw this comment now. Yes I've used getComponent().getClientId() before. Came up in the script editor auto complete. The below website shows examples of using getClientId('name'). http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/element_ids_in_client_side_javascript_on_xpages.htm

Comment: Working now.   Not sure what I was doing wrong before.   Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

try using:

```
var ef = dojo.byId('#{id'+errorField+'}');
ef.focus();
```

getElementsByName is looking for multiple elements with name="..." and returns an array. you can't set focus to an array of controls.

where as in XPages all controls have unique id's, so using dojo to search for ids will return a single element

Comment: Thanks Simon.  After adding a : (colon) after the id to get it to compile, I tried this but it did not work.  I even added an additional button right to my xPage with the same code to make sure it was not some strange problem with the extension library dialog and my OK button.

Comment: FYI The full client id for this control is:view:_id1:_id10:_id11:_id12:ccATM1:radioGroupCMBUAction  . Not sure how I would work that into my focus.

Comment: Simon's solution should work. Did you try to debug the above code (setting a break point using Firebug) to check if the code gets executed and has the correct ID?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the focus after the partial (or full) refresh is done.

```
        <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[ var ef = dojo.byId('#{javascript:getClientId(viewScope.get("errorField"))}');
                    ef.focus();]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
```